# How to install TortoiseSVN repository in Ubuntu machine?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, tortoisesvn

I have windows and Ubuntu14 running on my machine and I have to switch to Windows to commit code. Is is possible to install TortoiseSVN in my Ubuntu?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Tortoise SVN is Windows only, you can use the command line client, see [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svn.html) for help, or if you want a GUI you could try [RabbitVCS](http://rabbitvcs.org/) or [SmartSVN](http://www.smartsvn.com/).

---

To install rabbitvcs: | Update rabbitvcs-nautilus3 to rabbitvcs-nautilus package

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rabbitvcs/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-nautilus3
```

Then log out and back in to restart nautilus (or [How to restart nautilus without logging out?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19979/how-to-restart-nautilus-without-logging-out)).

You should then have RabbitVCS items on your right click context menu in the file browser.

Comment: Thanks, i have installed subversion by sudo apt-get install subversion for command line. but could not able to use rabbitVCS  even i have installed as per the instructions in the URL.i cold not see any GUI in my ubuntu still.Any help on that would really helps

Comment: PPA is not working Err:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release                                                                                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]

Comment: E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/rabbitvcs/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details

Comment: how can i remove it ?

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rabbitvcs/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-nautilus
```

Comment: Your answer is the same as the accepted one, other then your change from `nautilus3` to `nautilus`. Is that the name of the new package?

Comment: sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-nautilus3 is dont work for me.

Comment: @devugur try `sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-nautilus` , just remove 3 it will work